# Configure openseamap Tile Layer

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive, openseamap

I am using Leaflet with AngularJS through angular-leaflet-directive and I want to configure openseamap Tile Layer.

How can I do this?

I tried to replace openstreetmap URL with opensea map but it did not work.

```
 layers: {
          baselayers: {
              osm: {
                  name: 'openSeaMap',
                  url: 'http://tiles.openseamap.org/seamark/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                  type: 'xyz'
              }
          }
      },
```

console error message:

> main.js:17 [AngularJS - Leaflet] A layer must have a valid type defined.

Comment: Looks good. What exactly doesn't work? What does your browser error console say?

Comment: main.js:17 [AngularJS - Leaflet] A layer must have a valid type defined.

Comment: @scai please see the error message